# Usage Difference between to-infinitive and participle

Tags: infinitives, present-participles

I came across this question today.

> Q: the correct expression for blank.
>
> > The documents ____ immediate attention are on top.
>
> 1. Requiring 2. To require

I know the answer is *1. Requiring,* however I don't know why number 2 can't be an answer.

As far as I know, a to-infinitive can define a noun, like "books to read," so to me, number 2 can be an answer. But at the same time, I know "documents to require" looks very awkward. I just don't know why. Could you help me?

Answer (score 3):

You are right, in some cases you can use *to+infinitive* to describe a noun:

> I have books to read, work to do, people to call.

However, this only works with verbs that imply the action would be performed with the references nouns being the *object* of the action. That means that if I describe the actions from my earlier example being executed:

> I read books.
>   I do work.
>   I call people.

If the noun that you describe would be the *subject* of the action, this doesn't work:

> Documents require attention.
>   People read books.

In these cases you cannot describe *documents* or *people* using *to+infinitive*:

> *Documents to require attention
>   *People to read books

Instead, we use the active or present participle to describe them:

> Documents requiring attention
>   People reading books

Comment: Doesn't work. Some people read books. They're readers. Some people do books. They're accountants. *The people to do books are accountants*

Answer (score -1):

First of all (fussy point), I think you wrote 'documents' in its the singular form when it should in fact be plural (the 3rd-person plural verb 'are' refers to it later  in the sentence).

You should try to accustom yourself to the term 'documents requiring' so that you are more comfortable with that aspect of grammar. In general, try to read up on when it is appropriate to use present participles like `requiring`, and when you should use the infinitive, as in`to require`.

Comment: "Just learn it" hardly explains _why_ "I have books to read" is correct while "I have documents to require attention" is not. And the question was not whether _document to reuqire_ is correct, but _why_ it is incorrect.

Comment: You're never going to find an answer for that. Even if you do, it will be complex and grammatical and unsatisfying even if you can follow it. I agree I haven't given you a proper answer, but I don't think there _is_ a proper answer.

Comment: Have you read my answer? Is it incorrect, complex or unsatisfying? I agree it is grammatical - but that is kind of the whole point of this website. We like grammar here at ELU :)

Comment: Sorry @orkelens, I didn't bother scrolling up so I assumed that you were the person who had asked the question .  It's only that the person asking the question seemed not to _feel_ that the infinitive sounded wrong, so I was telling him to research it and make it sound right. That's mainly because I didn't have a proper answer myself and I did not believe that I could find one with any amount of research.Your answer proved me wrong, so +1.  Also, I was using 'grammatical' as a synonym for 'needlessly convoluted', but it was the wrong word in context now you mention it.